# How to retrieve <option> id to insert data into database

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with a dropdown list using `<select>` and `<option>` tags.
below that I have a textarea field.
The option ID's are the databases names, and I need to insert the `textarea`-input into the selected database.

Code:

**HTML FORM:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="selection" name="selection_name">
                    <option id="option1">First item</option>
                    <option id="option2">Second item</option>   
</select>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
 $dbToInsert = $_POST[''] // <-What do I insert here to get the selected option?
...
?>
```

Comment: show us your codes

Comment: `if ($code == 0) {echo "No Help!";}`

Comment: Tough crowd, I added the code :)
I know POST can retrieve data using the name tag, but can individual option also have a name tag? for example <option name="option"> and the use $_POST["option"]?

Answer (score 2):

You Should use "value" in option tag

```
<select name="vehicle">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

In the above example, if you have chosen "Audi", on form submission you will get the value "audi" in $_POST["vehicle"]